# how to avoid tweet id's getting truncated when saved in excel as csv

Tags: python, excel, twitter, twitterapi-python

i have around 2000 tweet id's for which i have to extract respective tweets. first and foremost thing excel doesnt allow me to save those tweet id in the same format as it is supposed to be and last four digits of the tweet id is truncated to 0000 .

ex : tweet id 572330170108922545 is truncated to 572330170108920000 .

i wanted to use twitter's tweepy library to extract tweets .. but seems that initial problem is not letting me start of the work. can i still use .txt file format to read each tweet id's line by line by using with open(filename.txt, 'r) as tweet_id :  ?

Please let me know if there is any work around for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to IEEE standard where only 15 digits of precision are allowed in excel. To fix this you can store them as strings ('572330170108922545') instead of numbers. [See here](https://superuser.com/questions/437764/why-is-excel-truncating-my-16-digit-numbers) for more detail

Comment: thanks @tofstie , that does solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

If your question is simply if this can be done, the answer is certainly yes. You just have to figure out how this data is structured. If you go line by line, you can use `.split()` or `re` (regular expression operations) to find the relevant parts of the lines.

Comment: i dont understand what  your trying to say .. @KaPy3141.. is it wrt excel ? because numbers have to be addressed in the beginning for which i can loop through the entire range of numbers in the excel file using for loop line by line.